# Sails V1.0 create a record with an id that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

I have the Users model and UserRol mode like this:

Users:

```
  primaryKey: 'id',

  attributes: {
    //  ╔═╗╦═╗╦╔╦╗╦╔╦╗╦╦  ╦╔═╗╔═╗
    //  ╠═╝╠╦╝║║║║║ ║ ║╚╗╔╝║╣ ╚═╗
    //  ╩  ╩╚═╩╩ ╩╩ ╩ ╩ ╚╝ ╚═╝╚═╝
    id: {
      type:'number',
      autoIncrement: true,
      columnName: 'user_id'
    },
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required:true
    },
    active: {
      type: 'boolean',
      defaultsTo: true
    },
    //  ╔═╗╔═╗╔═╗╔═╗╔═╗╦╔═╗╔╦╗╦╔═╗╔╗╔╔═╗
    //  ╠═╣╚═╗╚═╗║ ║║  ║╠═╣ ║ ║║ ║║║║╚═╗
    //  ╩ ╩╚═╝╚═╝╚═╝╚═╝╩╩ ╩ ╩ ╩╚═╝╝╚╝╚═╝
    userRol:{
      model: 'UserRol',
      columnName: 'user_rol_id',
      required: true
    }
  }
```

UserRol:

```
  primaryKey: 'id',
  tableName: 'user_rol',

  attributes: {
    //  ╔═╗╦═╗╦╔╦╗╦╔╦╗╦╦  ╦╔═╗╔═╗
    //  ╠═╝╠╦╝║║║║║ ║ ║╚╗╔╝║╣ ╚═╗
    //  ╩  ╩╚═╩╩ ╩╩ ╩ ╩ ╚╝ ╚═╝╚═╝
    id: {
      type: 'number',
      autoIncrement: true,
      columnName: 'user_rol_id'
    },
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      unique:true,
      required: true
    }
  }
```

With my database empthy (mysql). If i send a create request to user:

```
{
  "name": "john",
  "userRol": "2"
}
```

I will get :

```
{
    "createdAt": "2018-04-12T00:27:44.290Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-04-12T00:27:44.290Z",
    "id": 2,
    "name": "john",
    "active": true,
    "userRol": null
}
```

Because the userRoll id doesn't exist. In sails 0.12, there would be an error. But in this case it doesn't happen. In my models config, schema is enabled by default with null.
any ideas?